# Package JBoss AOP interceptors with business dependencies as a standalone application

Tags: java, maven, jboss, aop

**Here is my needs :**

I have a WebService application running on a JBoss 5.1 (with a jboss-classloading configuration export-all=NON_EMPTY and import-all=true).
I want to add some interceptors on it but I can't change the legacy WS WAR.

**What is my problems :**

I managed to get working a simple interceptor packaged in a JAR that basically log every calls on legacy WebService.
But to achieve my goal, I need to use JAR dependencies like XML parsers, business objects, etc...

How can I package my AOP interceptors and its dependencies in one file ?

**What I've tried :**

In a WAR package, I have to use a similar jboss-classloading strategy to avoid conflicts, but in this context, I can't intercept anything else than classes in the WAR itself, so I can't intercept legacy WS calls.

PS : I have made all the basics to get JBoss AOP working properly :

- `pluggable-instrument.jar` in bin folder
- run.conf with `-javaagent:pluggable-instrumentor.jar`
- `aop.xml` with loadTimeWeaving enabled and include package defined
- `jboss-aop.xml` with valid pointcuts configurations (which I want in my package)

Answer (score 0):

For now I found a solution by building a SAR package (JBoss Service Archive).

The SAR file look like this :

**aop-interceptors.sar**

- META-INF/`jboss-service.xml`
- aop-interceptors.jar

  - META-INF/`jboss-aop.xml`
  - com.mypackage.aop.interceptors...
  - com.mypackage.aop.handlers...
  - com.mypackage.aop.business.logic...
- xml-parsers.jar
- business-objects.jar
- ...

The SAR file is deployed in folder : jboss-5.1/server/default/deployers/jboss-aop-jboss5.deployer/

I don't know what SAR package is supposed to do ... is there a better way to do it ?